# mat-tab on clicking first time after cdk-virual scroll showing empty data, navigating back from 1st tab to 2nd tab works

Tags: angular-material, infinite-scroll, mat-tab, angular-cdk-virtual-scroll

i am using cdk scroll for acordian, dynamically generated from api, (if page end is reached again i will hit the api), and append the records, n numbers, if i open an accordian i have 2 tabs, mat-tab, on clicking the second tab, i have to load the data (table), it is coming correctly, but when api hits 2nd time, on scroll, then if i open an accordian 2nd mat-tab, data is empty, if i go back to 1st tab, then again click the 2nd tab, data is coming,need to resolve

Tried to populate the 2nd tab details inside accordian from server side rendering , infinite scrolling achieved using cdk-virtual scroll

Comment: since, i was due to the cdkscroll, it was adding some inline style hidden for the tab, so i have overridden that by applying the following css as a temporary fix, but i wonder, why hidden css  is added by cdk for an activ

:host ::ng-deep.mat-mdc-tab-body-active .mat-mdc-tab-body-content {
 display: block;
 visibility: visible !important;
}